# Can't boot win 7 from GRUB, but can from its own bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a drive where I already had Win 7 installed in UEFI mode. Ubuntu installer nicely detected Windows and added it to the GRUB menu. However, when I choose the appropriate option in the menu, Windows doesn't boot showing just a black screen.

Pressing F12 I can get a so-called one-time boot menu, from which I can choose from which device a system should boot. There is a **legacy** section with all physical drives, and **UEFI** with two options: windows and Ubuntu. When I select Windows here, it starts normally. Ubuntu starts into GRUB.

How can I fix GRUB to load Windows properly?

Ubuntu was installed from USB formatted as GPT for UEFI.

Comment: Inside Ubuntu, run `sudo update-grub`, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @AndroidDev Unfortunately, it didn't help.